# Why wont this work?

Tags: magento-1.9, sidebar, products-view

I using this code sucessfully on one site inside of the sidebar.phtml but im trying to reuse on another template another site and have tried both the sidebar.phtml and the view.phtml and it breaks the page whereever i insert it

```
 <div class="race2">
        <?php $salesbanner = $_product->getAttributeText('salesbanner'); $salesbannerImage = str_replace(' ', '_', $salesbanner) . ".png"; $salesbannerLink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $salesbanner)) . ".html"; $salesbannerBaseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl() . '/shop-by-brand/'; ?> <?php echo $brandBaseUrl . $brandLink; ?> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/media/" . $salesbannerImage); ?>"  /> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either not giving your full code, or you have a problem with your variable names:

```
echo $brandBaseUrl . $brandLink;
```

Both variables don't exist in the code you provided. It would make more sense to use:

```
echo $salesbannerBaseUrl.$salesbannerLink;
```